# How many wives can a Christian have?

Tags: catholicism, protestantism, marriage, polygamy

How many wives can a Christian have is it allowed to have 4 or 3 wives? Can I have marriage of multiple women as a believing christian?

Comment: As a Christian you can have multiple wives but not at the same time. Some Christians allow divorce and some don't. You need to specify denomination. You can't have all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The norm in for the vast majority of Christians is one wife, and the Bible stipulates that church leaders may have no more than one.

- Now a bishop must be above reproach, the husband of one wife, temperate, sensible, dignified, hospitable, an apt teacher... (1 Timothy 3:2)
- Let deacons be the husband of one wife, and let them manage their children and their households well (1 Timothy 3:12)
- appoint elders in every town as I directed you, if any man is blameless, the husband of one wife, and his children are believers and not open to the charge of being profligate or insubordinate. (Titus 1:5-6)

No major worldwide denomination allows its members to have more than one wife. However other churches do, especially among the [African Independent Churches](https://christianhistoryinstitute.org/magazine/article/african-way-independent-churches) that compete with Muslim populations for members and polygamy is not banned by the state. Some of these churches have millions of members. The number of wives allowed varies. In the USA and elsewhere, polygamy is allowed in Mormon fundamentalist churches and a few smaller groups.

Additional information is available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamy_in_Christianity#)

Comment: Even in the Hebrew scriptures, the few documented instances of polygamy involved men that were rich and powerful. It was not the normal practice of society.

Comment: +1 "the husband of one wife" My understanding is the word translated 'one' here can also be translated 'first', and so a minoritarian translation could be 'husband of his first wife', as in still married to his first wife. A bit puzzling you don't mention this used to be a standard practice among Mormons (starting in 1843), and only officially un-supported in 1890 when it looked like the U.S. government would destroy the church over it, and in 1904 polygamy was accompanied by a threat of excommunication by the church. https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/americanexperience/features/mormons-polygamy/

Comment: The omission of LDS historical practices was an oversight. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is going to be different depending on what authority you give credence to.

By the authority of scripture, there is nothing explicit that forbids polygamy. No less a figure than Martin Luther said

> "I confess that I cannot forbid a person to marry several wives, for
> it does not contradict the Scripture. If a man wishes to marry more
> than one wife he should be asked whether he is satisfied in his
> conscience that he may do so in accordance with the word of God. In
> such a case the civil authority has nothing to do in the matter." (De
> Wette II, 459, ibid., pp. 329-330)

Combine the weak scriptural basis for not allowing polygamy (the strongest straightforward scriptural argument is from Paul's advice in 1 Timothy 3 and Titus 1 regarding bishops, deacons, and elders - not everyone, and even there there is some grammatical ambiguity as to whether they are to have only 1 wife or rather be still married to their 1st wife) - as testified by Luther's account - with it seemingly coming from Roman traditions, not Jewish, and you have a bit of a conundrum.

If, however, you grant authority to a specific church, the large majority of churches teach you can only have one spouse, but have varying rules on divorce, and so typically allow for serial polygamy under certain circumstances.

Comment: It's interesting to reflect upon the first century practices among the Jewish people, as recorded in the Talmud - of which the first stages were published in the late 2nd century. In legal matters pertaining to marriage they accounted for the possibility of more than one wife - e.g. the Talmud discusses how to divide an estate between multiple wives. With the shortage of men, as the result of gay marriages being more popular, one might argue that the adoption of polygamy in the west might help alleviate the problem of a shortage of eligible men for women to mate with.

Comment: @Jess Yes, seems to have been an accepted background practice to some extent in 1st century Judaism, and there can be practical arguments for it (such as war which depletes the male population). And of course certain high-profile figures in Judaism had multiple wives. Lamech, Abraham, Jacob, Moses, Gideon, Elkanah, David (8 wives approved by God in 2 Samuel), and of course Solomon (but he went overboard, Deut. 17:17 forbidding kings from taking 'excessive' wives). I think the better question is whether this is the ideal, or an accommodation (as Jesus says the laws of divorce were).

Comment: @OTG, on a sliding scale of interpreting sexual boundaries in the Bible I'd say that there is just us much, if not more, of a compelling case to be made for allowing polygamous marriages than for gay marriages. The "two (oppostie genders) shall become one" is what I read in the pre-fall Genesis ideal pattern. Adding an extra person or so to the mix might complicate matters, but it still keeps a Yin/Yang symbolism intact.

Comment: @Jess I don't think the Bible even allows for the conceptual possibility of same-sex 'marriage'. Same-sex couples might cohabitate, or be called 'married' by a state, but it would be like redefining the word 'dog' to include cats. They're still cats, not dogs.

Comment: OTG, if one allows for polygamy, one could just add an extra opposite gender in the mix to make that gay couple polygamous. Problem solved, perhaps?

Comment: @Jess Not sure what problem needs solving - you've lost me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141857/discussion-between-jess-and-only-true-god).

Answer (score 2):

According to the Torah, a man could have two, three, or even four wives. But we must consider the rivalry between Jacob's wives and the rivalry between Sarah and Hagar. King Solomon went way overboard and married "foreign" (non-Hebrew) wives. Again, according to Torah, a man was free to take a concubine.
Today, however, that would go over like a lead brick swimming in the ocean.
The Book of Romans tells us that we are to obey the laws of our land. Therefore, plural marriage is prohibited. There is no "Command" in Torah telling a man he must have an additional wife. The ideal marriage was between Isaac and Rebecca -- one man, one wife. Then too, two wives -- two mothers-in-law! Who wants that?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).